# Does anyone know what font this is?

Tags: integration

I am trying to figure out how to produce this exact integral sign (in pdfLaTeX, if possible; if not, in Microsoft Word?). Would anyone know how to? I know that it's really specific, but it could really make the difference for me in a class. I've also attached an image of this integral with an integrand. Thank you!
[The integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy9Ac.png) [The integral with an integrand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV7G4.png)

Comment: There is a site in the SE network dedicated to LaTeX. I believe your question has been asked here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222243/how-to-obtain-a-bold-upright-integral-sign

Comment: Also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/971/what-font-package-do-i-use-to-get-the-vertical-russian-german-style-integral-sig

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. If you ever struggle to find LaTeX for a symbol, [you can draw it](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). If the famous `\int` isn't what you want, try e.g. `\textesh`; I'd never heard of it, but the suggestion came up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Computer Modern Unicode Serif (also known as CMU Serif) and should be available as a TTF download for Windows which means can then be used in Word and/or PDFs.